# Adding data from one mongo document to different mongo document with aggreagation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This situation is a little confusing, so I will do my best to explain with this example.

Lets say I have an object (mongoDb document) that looks like:

```
{
  _id: 0989sd7f987123bnkmsdfv,
  name: 'Item-004',
  itemId: 004,
  date: 10/11/1960,
  color: 'green',
  quantity: 21,
  listOfItems: [
   {
     itemId: 001, 
     itemName: 'Item-001',
     color: 'blue'
   },
   {
     itemId: 002, 
     itemName: 'Item-002',
     color: 'orange'
   },
   {
     itemId: 003, 
     itemName: 'Item-003',
     color: 'purple'
   }
  ]
}
```

This is an object in the `items` collection. `listOfItems` is an array that is comprised of other items in the same collection, but the problem is that the array doesn't have enough details about the items. Every Item has a `name`, `date`, `itemId`, `color`, `quantity`, and `listOfItems` array. How can I write an aggregation query to add those fields to the item in the `listOfItems` array.

end result/ goal:

```
{
_id: 0989sd7f987123bnkmsdfv,
  name: 'Item-004',
  itemId: 004,
  date: 10/11/1960,
  color: 'green',
  quantity: 21,
  listOfItems: [
   { 
     itemId: 001, 
     name: 'Item-001',
     date: 12/12/1996,
     color: 'blue',
     quantity: 33,
   },
   {
     itemId: 002, 
     name: 'Item-002',
     date: 08/11/2021,
     color: 'orange',
     quantity: 1045,
   },
   {
     itemId: 003, 
     name: 'Item-003',
     date: 03/30/1998
     color: 'purple'
     quantity: 9,
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$listOfItems"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "listOfItems.itemId",
      "foreignField": "itemId",
      "as": "listOfItems"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$listOfItems"
  },
  {
    "$unset": "listOfItems.listOfItems"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        name: "$name",
        itemId: "$itemId",
        date: "$date",
        color: "$color",
        quantity: "$quantity"
      },
      "listOfItems": {
        "$push": "$listOfItems"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$_id",
          {
            listOfItems: "$listOfItems"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace",
      
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the corresponding playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KC2e06COmH_).

Comment: When I try to implement this in my real world issue, its returning me an empty array. Could this be because the object has a more complicated structure?

Comment: Most likely you'll have to update the pipeline to match your object structure.